# Python metaclass for inner classes

Tags: python, object-oriented, classes

This is a metaclass for facilitating the concept of "inner classes" (as opposed to simple nested classes) in Python. I define an inner class as a nested class that expects an instance of the outer class as
the first argument to `__new__` and `__init__`.

This metaclass implements the
descriptor protocol (non-data) for the inner class, such that calling the inner
class through an attribute access on an instance of the outer class will
automatically pass the latter as the first argument to the constructor of the
inner class.

Example:

```py
class Car:
    class Motor(metaclass=InnerClassMeta):
        def __init__(self, car: "Car"):
            self.car = car
```

```py
>>> car = Car()
>>> motor = car.Motor()
>>> motor.car is car
True
```

This is similar to Java's inner classes.

I'm mainly concerned with correctness, consistent behaviour, and maintainability. Note: this doesn't attempt to discriminate from which class it is being accessed,
i.e. it doesn't attempt to validate that it is being accessed from the outer class
in which it was defined (if any).

Code:

```py
class InnerClassMeta(type):
    """Metaclass for inner classes."""

    class BoundInnerClass:
        def __init__(self, inner_class, outer_instance):
            self.inner_class = inner_class
            self.outer_instance = outer_instance

        def __repr__(self):
            return (
                f"<bound inner class {self.inner_class.__name__}"
                f" of {self.outer_instance}>"
            )

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return self.inner_class(self.outer_instance, *args, **kwargs)

    def __get__(cls, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return cls  # don't bind to classes, just instances
        return InnerClassMeta.BoundInnerClass(cls, instance)
```